# Reference to external stacklayout component ID inside xaml.cs file in xaml Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I am making a xaml file inheret from a stackLayout component. I have called this TimerButton.

I have two TimerButtons and want to differentiate between them.

```
//In MainPage.xaml   
<component:TimerButton x:Name="Smoke"></component:TimerButton>  
<component:TimerButton x:Name="Snuff"></component:TimerButton>
```

I need to send in the ID  so that I can set a value in the C# code (ViewModel.TobaccoType) inside the TimerButton component. I have tried using the x: arguments/name/type with no luck.

```
//In TimerButton.xaml.cs
ViewModel = new TimerButtonViewModel();

if (this.FindByName<TimerButton>("Smoke") != null)
{
     ViewModel.TobaccoType = "Smoke";
}
```

Comment: Thats what i tried to do with x:Name. But can't reach it inside the Timerbutton.xaml.cs file.

Comment: Well, i need it to run the code  at the initialization of the button. I want to know if it is a snuff button or smoke button, without having to make SmokeTimerButton and SnuffTimerButton each as components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following. Give the TimerButton a so called [DependencyProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh700353.aspx) like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TobaccoTypeProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "TobaccoType", typeof(String),
    typeof(TimerButton), null);

public String TobaccoType
{
   get { return (String)GetValue(TobaccoTypeProperty); }
   set { SetValue(TobaccoTypeProperty, value); }
}
```

And then you refer to it in your XAML like this:

```
//In MainPage.xaml   
<component:TimerButton x:Name="Smoke" TobaccoType="Smoke"></component:TimerButton>  
<component:TimerButton x:Name="Snuff" TobaccoType="Snuff"></component:TimerButton>
```

This properties you can easily refer in your TimerButton.cs

Comment: This helped a lot. Although Xamarin uses BindableProperty instead of DependencyProperty and Create instead of register. Thanks for the help.